# KendoUI grid minlength not working

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

can KendoUI grid enforce minlength validation. I have some troubles with it. Look at the screenshot.

I have set minlength and maxlength. It doesn't allow me to enter more than 10 letters, however, I can enter less than 2 letters and update the entry in grid.

Is this Kendo issue?

[image: Developer Tools screenshot]

Comment: Can you add your code for validation? Are you also doing custom validation by any chance?

Comment: No, no custom validation, I've just set minlength field as validation with value 2 into fields...

Comment: Ah I think I see the issue. Basically, there is no minlength attribute in Html5, so you can't constrain it that way. You have to use custom validation. Let me know if you need help with that. Regarding custom validation, there _are_ some known bugs with that not completely working right.

Comment: Actually, I found a way to do it with the pattern attribute, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, minlength doesn't work because that attribute doesn't exist in HTML5 whereas maxlength does.

Instead, you have to use custom validation, or use the pattern attribute.

**Pattern Attribute**

```
my_name {
     validation: {
          required: true,
          pattern:'.{2,10}'
     }
},
```

This means that `my_name` must be between 2 to 10 characters. It will allow you to type less or more, but will throw invalid message when you try to update.

**Custom Validation:**

```
my_name {
     validation: {
          required: true,
          lengthRule: function (input) {
               if (input.is("[name='DirectionName']") && input.val() !== "") {
                    input.attr("data-lengthRule-msg", "My Name must be between 2 to 10 characters.");
                    return (input.val().length<=10 && input.val().length>=2);
               }
               return true;
          },
     }
},
```

With the latter method, there is a known bug, so I am not to keen on using the latter method.

**Custom Valiation Bug FYI:** [Validation is not always triggered when editing with backspace](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-error-on-grid-custom-validation)

Comment: if i use pattern attribute, how can i custom the validation message? thanks